# Visual Studio Code Project Folder Not Working

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have sf CLI installed, JDK 11 installed, salesforce extension installed, vsc installed.  after initial create a project using standard template, in new project folder, nothing shows up.  also, did the authorize an org, nothing shows up.  Powershell sfdx not recognized.  In Environment Variables, the paths are there.  also, have uninstalled and reinstalled everything and still nothing shows up?
I have spent everyday the last 5 days watched you tube, read vs docs, install, uninstall.
Please help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have any view in your explorer in Visual Studio Code, and it will help if you can provide detail, maybe video or something that help others understand the nature of your problem.

For now, try to follow this step on this link below it explains about views being the issue relating to your kind of question.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/32962